# How to offset Geometry nodes rotation while scaling instances?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Here is the thing. I'm making an animation using geometry nodes, and i'm using weight paint to scale some instances:

[image]

That, is making this:

[image]

This is rotating and scaling but the rotation is not visible because is at the same time as the scaling.

The thing is, i would like to use the same weight to not only make the instances go from 0 to 1, but to rotate the instances while doing this but with a small offset, so i can see the rotation during the animation. At the moment, because the rotation and the scaling is happening at the same time, can't see the rotation.

Here is the rotation:

[image]

Here is my Geo node (very simple)

[image]

So my question is, anyone knows how to **offset** my rotation, so it's a bit after start the scaling?

I'm basically looking for something like this but for all the instances and without keyframes:

[image]

Comment: Your real problem is that you take a **float value** in range $[0; 1]$, and interpret it as a boolean *Selection*, which is a common mistake, caused by creating a group input socket by dragging from an empty "ghost" socket to a boolean *Selection* socket of another node. Press the **N** key to open the *Numbers Panel*, change the type to float, and now your animation won't suddenly flip the scales from 0 to 1. Similarly, as the squares now smoothly grow to their size, they will also smoothly rotate.

Comment: You can still explicitly convert the float to boolean using e.g. "Compare: greater than 0" node for scale, but using the smooth transition for rotation. And finally, if the transition in the vertex group is too short, you can use a simulation zone to increase the length of the transition.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady you were right, switching to float and adjusting some parameters with a compare and a math node did the trick, thanks. If you add it as answer I can mark it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your real problem is that you take a ⚫ float value in range $[0; 1]$, and interpret it as a  boolean *Selection*, which is a common mistake, caused by creating a group input socket by dragging from an empty "ghost" socket to a boolean Selection socket of another node. Press the <kbd>N</kbd> key to open the Numbers Panel, change the type to float, and now your animation won't suddenly flip the scales from 0 to 1. Similarly, as the squares now smoothly grow to their size, they will also smoothly rotate.

You can still explicitly convert the float to boolean using e.g. *Compare: greater than 0* node for scale, but using the smooth transition for rotation. And finally, if the transition in the vertex group is too short, you can use a simulation zone to increase the length of the transition (e.g. use the vertex group as speed of change, by which you increment the actual animated value).